# only first form is checked by jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

i have one form on my page. so i want to check each input with corresponding button. so i wrote smth like this and it only checks first input even if i click on second inputs button.

```
<form target="myFrame" method="post" id="addProduct">
          <fieldset>
           <input type="hidden" name="iProductAdd" value="6" />
           <input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="aProducts[6]" autocomplete="off"  value="" maxlength="4" size="4"  onclick="function()"  class="quantity" />
           <input type="submit" onclick="refreshIframe();" value="" class="addtobasket" id="addtobasket" />
         </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
           <input type="hidden" name="iProductAdd" value="7" />
           <input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="aProducts[7]" autocomplete="off"  value="" maxlength="4" size="4"  onclick="function()"  class="quantity" />
           <input type="submit" onclick="refreshIframe();" value="" class="addtobasket" id="addtobasket" />
         </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
           <input type="hidden" name="iProductAdd" value="4" />
           <input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="aProducts[4]" autocomplete="off"  value="" maxlength="4" size="4"  onclick="function()"  class="quantity" />
           <input type="submit" onclick="refreshIframe();" value="" class="addtobasket" id="addtobasket" />
         </fieldset>
        </form>
```

and i have jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").submit(function(){

// Get the Login Name value and trim it
 var name = $.trim($('.quantity').val());

// Check if empty of not
  if (name === '') {
    $("#addtobasket").css("background-image", "url('http://restorani.weby.biz/templates/default/img/tick-red.png')");
    return false;
 } else {
     $('input[type="submit"]').each(function(){
             $("#addtobasket").css("background-image", "url('http://restorani.weby.biz/templates/default/img/tick-green.png')");
     });
 }
});
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using ids as it were classes. An id should be unique in a document. So defining multiple objects with the same id is an error. And all functions will apply only the first they encounter. To do what you want, you have to use classes, so change your code in this way:

```
$(".addtobasket").css("background-image", "url('http://restorani.weby.biz/templates/default/img/tick-green.png')");
```

To look for all elements of that class.

Comment: I mostly agree with this. But I don't think HTML specifies what happens when you abuse `id` in this way; it may be that some browsers or versions of jQuery use the last element with the id instead of the first one.

Comment: mark91 is right. Also: `$('.quantity')` is a jQuery element which refers to 3 different HTML elements, but `$('.quantity').val()` only tells you the value of the first one. So the first number input controls the colours of all 3 submit buttons. This isn't what you wanted.

Comment: @DavidKnipe, I don't know if HTML specify this or not, but in the most used browser (IE, FX, Chrome) I can ensure you that the behaviour is the same: the first element is returned... However we are talking of an *error*, because there shouldn't be two elements with the same id.